# JSOUP / HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsoup

I am using JSOUB  to scrape all the web page as the following:

```
   public static final String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";

   String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q="+searchTerm+"&num="+num + 
      "&start=" + start;


    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31")
           // .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
            .maxBodySize(1024*1024*3) 
            .followRedirects(true)
            .timeout(100000)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .get();


    Elements results = doc.select("h3.r > a");

      for (Element result : results) {

        String linkHref = result.attr("href");
     }
```

But my problem is that at the start of the code working good.

after a while, it will stop and always gives me " HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503  error".

when I add the .ignoreHttpErrors(true) it will work without any error but it will not scrape the web.

*search term is any keyword I want to search about and num is the number of pages that I need to retrieve.

could anyone help, please?
Is this mean that Google blocked my IP from scraping? if yes is there any solution or how I scape the google search result, please?

I need help.
Thank you,

Comment: The unaccepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614919/google-crawl-503-service-unavailable might shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

503 error usually means the website you trying to scrap blocks you because they don't want non-human user navigating their sites. Especially Google.

There are something you can do though. Such as

- Using proxy rotator
- Use chromedriver
- Add some delays to your application after each page

Basically you need to be as human as possible to prevent sites blocking you.

**EDIT:**

I need to warn you that scraping Google search result is against their ToS and might be illegal depends on where you are.

**What you can do**

You can use proxy rotating service to mask your request so google will see it as request from multiple region. Google `proxy rotator service` if you interested. It might be expensive depends on what you do with the data.

Then code some module that change the `User-Agent` every request to make Google less suspicious with your request.

Add random delay after scraping each page. I suggest around 1-5 seconds. Randomized delay makes your request more human-like for Google

At last if everything fails, you might want to look into Google search API and use their API instead of scraping their site.

Comment: thank you for your solution.
I add some delays to my application after each page and it works for some time. But now it stops working. What I mean there is nothing in "results" variable in the code.
please, could you help I am new in the web scraping?
is it possible to scrape the web? I can not use a different IP address.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Well that's the sign that Google detects you crawling their site. You get nothing in `results` because Google returns 503 Error which mean you are prohibited to access the site before you verify you are a human. Which your crawler not. As I said earlier, you have to code your crawler to mimic human behavior as much as possible. Delay is one thing but other thing such as `Cookies` or `HTTP Headers` also play part for Google in analyzing your request. I updated my answer for more details.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, please it posiple to take permission from Google to do this in research?... please what is proxy rotator service? do you recommend something?

Comment: please, could I add some restriction or filtering to the search result that I do not need any images or video??

Comment: I personally use `stormproxies` for the proxy rotator, for permission they did have API that you can use but it's not free. And I doubt you can get permission from them to use it for free.

Comment: In web scraping there is no such thing as video or image. All you get is HTML file that you can parse.